# Recursion With Tuples in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, tuples

I want to define a simple function in Haskell:

```
    nzp :: [Int] -> (Int,Int,Int)
```

that accepts a list of integers as input  and returns a triple (a,b,c) where a is the amount of numbers in the list less than 0, b is the amount equal to 0 and c is the amount higher than zero. For example,

```
    nzp [3,0,-2,0,4,5] = (1,2,3)
```

I have to define this function recursively and I can only traverse the list once. How can I do this? I can't seem to grasp the concept of recursively creating a tuple.

Most Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some pointers:

1. To use recursion to build up a value, you need to pass the previous version of the value as an argument, so write

   ```
   nzp_helper :: [Int] -> (Int,Int,Int) -> (Int, Int, Int)
   ```
2. Decide what the answer is when the list is empty

   ```
   nzp_helper [] runningTotals = -- what's the answer if the list is empty?
   ```
3. Decide what the answer is when there's something in the list

   ```
   nzp_helper (i:is) (negatives, positives, zeros) = 
         | i < 0 = -- write stuff here
         | i == 0 = -- I hope you're getting the idea
   ```
4. Kick the whole thing off by defining `nzp` using `nzp_helper`.

   ```
   nzp is = nzp_helper is -- one final argument - what?
   ```

Comment: Very good answer--it helps to understand how to create recursive functions generally. :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of thinking of trying to create a single tuple recursively, you should think about updating an existing tuple containing the counts based on given value. This function would look something like:

```
update :: (Int, Int, Int) -> Int -> (Int, Int, Int)
update (l,e,g) x | x < 0 = (l+1, e, g)
update (l,e,g) x | x == 0 = (l, e+1, g)
update (l,e,g) x | x > 0 = (l, e, g+1)
```

Then you can traverse the input list using `foldl` and accumulate the output tuple:

```
nzp :: [Int] -> (Int, Int, Int)
nzp = foldl update (0,0,0)
```

EDIT: As @leftroundabout points out in the comments, you should avoid using `foldl` since it can lead to space leaks - you can find an explanation [in Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/functional-programming.html#id594142). You can use the strict version of `foldl`, `foldl'` in Data.List

```
import Data.List
nzp = foldl' update (0,0,0)
```

Comment: Except `foldl` is basically bad. Depending on the strictness properties, use `foldr` or (actually correct in this case) `foldl'`. But in doubt I'd recommend sticking to `foldr`: it's easiest to grasp (replace each `:` with the function and `[]` with the init value) and behaves ideal in lazy contexts.

Comment: Thanks, I've done it. the thing is that I was not supposed to use high order functions (at least explicitly) but I managed to do it.

Comment: @leftaroundabout - Thanks, I didn't know that about `foldl`.

Comment: However, `foldl'` only really helps vs `foldl` if you have a strict accumulator type. In case of tuples, the tuple is only evaluated to its WHNF `(_,_,_)` so it still accumulates larger and larger thunks in the tuple elements. If you want to have a strict fold for multiple values, you need to define your own accumulator type with strict fields or use bang patterns on the tuple elements in your step function.

Answer (score 2):

> I can't seem to grasp the concept of recursively creating a tuple.

I shouldn't think so – in fact, it's impossible! (At least not without GHC extension havoc.)

No, you need to create a tuple in one go. The important thing needed for your function: since you may only traverse the list once, you need to pull through the entire tuple at once as well. As this is apparently homework, I shall instead show how it works with a fold (that is in fact preferrable, but translates quite directly to recursion):

```
nzp = foldr switchIncr (0,0,0)
 where switchIncr x (negatives, zeroes, positives)
         | x<0        = (succ negatives, zeroes, positives)
         | x==0       = (negatives, succ zeroes, positives)
         | otherwise  = (negatives, zeroes, succ positives)
```

Comment: He probably needs to write his own version of a fold which is where the recursion would come in.

Comment: Thanks, I've done it. the thing is that I was not supposed to use high order functions (at least explicitly) but I managed to do it.

Answer (score 1):

New to Haskell too! Perhaps not proper but here is my solution which works.
Define an auxiliary function that accumulates the n,z, and p values

```
let f (x:xs, (n, z, p)) | x < 0 = f (xs, (n+1, z, p))
                        | x == 0 = f (xs, (n, z+1, p))
                        | otherwise = f (xs, (n, z, p+1))
    f ([], (n, z, p)) = ([], (n, z, p))
```

and define nzp in terms of the auxiliary function

```
 let nzp x = snd $ f (x,(0,0,0))
```

to verify

```
Prelude> nzp [-1,1,1,-1,0]
(2,1,2)
```

Comment: Note that it's convention in Haskell to define functions in curried form, i.e. `f (x:xs) (n,z,p) | ...`. Not only is that less writing of parens and commas, it also allows you to deal with higher-order functions much more comfortably (η-conversion can avoid or at least reduce need for lambda functions).

Comment: It would then be Haskell curry form?

Answer (score 1):

I am a little over a couple of months into Haskell. A helper/auxilliary function would make running this solution easier.

```
s3 [] (l,g,z) = (l,g,z)
s3 (x:xs) (l,g,z) = if      x<0
                    then        (s3 xs (l+1,g,z))
                    else if x>0
                         then   (s3 xs (l,g+1,z))
                         else   (s3 xs (l,g,z+1))
```

This is run with `s3 [1,0,-2,3,4,-7,0,-8] (0,0,0)` producing
`(3,3,2)`.

Just about any primitive recursive function can be translated into a fold.